# Proofs by contradiction and set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm having trouble understanding proofs by contradiction. I'm running things by memory and not by understanding what a contradiction is. I'd like to know what we're assuming and how to start. My understanding is that if we have $p \rightarrow q$ it suffices to show $p \land \lnot q$ and we starting with $\lnot q$.

Here are two examples I found:

$$(A-B) \cap (B-A)=\emptyset \\ \text and \\ |A \cup B| = |A| +|B| \rightarrow A\cap B =\emptyset   $$

Well, for this first one, I don't have an if/then statement so do I just assume that $(A-B) \cap (B-A)  \neq \emptyset$ ? I know that this set is the empty by simple logic rules.

For the second one, do I assume $p \land \lnot q$ for  $ \lnot (A\cap B =\emptyset)  $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to prove that $(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)=\varnothing$ for all $A$ and $B$, you can begin by assuming that $(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)\ne\varnothing$. Then let $x\in(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)$; clearly $x\in A\setminus B$, so $x\in A$. But also $x\in B\setminus A$, so $x\notin A$. This is a contradiction, so the original assumption that $(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)\ne\varnothing$ must be false. If $p$ is this assumption, and $q$ is $x\in A$, then the argument shows that $p\to(q\land\neg q)$. However

$$\Big(p\to(q\land\neg q)\Big)\to\neg p$$

is a tautology, so we infer $\neg p$, i.e., that $(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)=\varnothing$.

I would prove the second one by showing that

$$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|\;;$$

it follows immediately that if $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$, then $|A\cap B|=0$ and hence that $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Comment: I got lost where you subtracted $|A \cap B|$, why would we do that?

Comment: @Dimitri: Maybe it’s easier to think about it in the form $$|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|\;.$$ When you calculate $|A|+|B|$, you count each element of $A\cap B$ twice, one as a member of $A$ and once as a member of $B$, so to get the actual number of elements in $A\cup B$ you have to subtract the amount of overcounting, which is $|A\cap B|$.

Comment: Gotcha. Proofs need a lot of work and intuition and the time period given to learn is short.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $p \rightarrow q$ by contradiction, one assumes to the contrary that $p \wedge \neg q$ holds and then tries to prove a contradiction, which is a statement of the form $r \wedge \neg r$, where $r$ is any formula you like.

*Remark.* We can compute the negation of $p \rightarrow q$ as follows:

$$\neg(p \rightarrow q) = \neg (\neg p \vee q) = \neg \neg p \wedge \neg q = p \wedge \neg q$$

So its negation really is $p \wedge \neg q$.